# Undefined Columns Selected (Not a comma issue)

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a subset of a data frame I've created  and am getting what appears to be a common error "...undefined columns selected...".  Most solutions suggest a simple misplaced error but I believe my code is correct.

I've tested different combinations of variables in the subset and it's clear it's the last three variables creating the issues. Analysis has shown there are no NAs in the fields  They're all fields within a larger list called SOURCE_DATA. I'm looking for any suggestion as to why I might be receiving this error. The link below is to a photo of the Data and Values descriptions in RStudio.

[image: Data - Variables]

```
DATA_SUBSET <- SOURCE_DATA[,unique(c(IDVars, InterventionVar, OutcomeVars, ControlVars, ConditionalVars))]

Error in `[.data.frame`(SOURCE_DATA, , unique(c(IDVars, InterventionVar,  : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Comment: For each of your variable-name vectors, e.g. `IDVars`, do this and make sure you get all TRUEs: `IDVars %in% names(SOURCE_DATA)`.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. Without any of your data, we have no way of knowing whether all those names are accurately the names of columns in that data frame

Comment: DanY - thank you that helped me narrow down the error (missing underscores in three items).